# Unity: Editor application Install failed: Unity Hub does not have permission to access the folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, download

I have tried repeatedly without success to install a late version of Unity (2021.3.13f1 and 2021.3.12f1) from Unity Hub 3.3.0 on my MacBook Pro 16 (running macOS Monterey version 12.6). Consistently I get the error: "Editor application Install failed: Unity Hub does not have permission to access the folder..." - the folder currently being /System/Applications. I have tried different destination folders but the result was always the same.

I am not behind a firewall. Questions posted on Stack Overflow similar to mine usually have no accepted answer or a solution that seems not to apply in my case.
[image: Here's a screenshot of the outcome of my latest attempt:]

Unity downloads for me always seem to be an ordeal, more difficult than for any other software I use. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: [Possibly relevant - install to a user folder instead](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unity-editor-install-via-hub-fails-silently-when-installing-it-on-mac-account-without-admin-privileges).

Comment: Mickey, I had tried that before without success, but I tried it again at your prompting, though to yet another folder, and the installation was successful. Thank you.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to hear you got it going.  Pesky Macs ;)

Answer (score 12):

In the Finder, go to `/Applications/Unity` and open the Information window (e.g. right-click the folder and select *Get Info*).

Go the the Sharing and Permissions section, and see if the current user or group has Read & Write permissions.

**If not**, click the padlock in the lower right corner to unlock and allow editing the settings.

Change the privilege to Read & Write for the current user/group.

**If you or your group isn’t even in the list**, click the “+“ to add the current user/group to the access list, then give that user/group Read & Write privileges.
*(For example, I added the admin group, which I'm a member of, to the list.)*

Then, go to the "..." pulldown next the the +/- buttons and select "Apply to enclosed items...".
*(This may be overkill, you should just need to do it for the relevant folders, but I was tired of fooling around and wanted it to "just work"!)*

The install can now be retried and should succeed.
(There is no need to restart the Unity Hub.)